# What am i missing in this layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a layout like this for each row of a listview

[image]

So i created a container like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:clickable="false"
              android:focusable="false"
        >

    <!--List items goes here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

In the getView() method of my custom adapter, I inflate this xml for each box in the image above

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="300dp"
                 android:layout_height="500dp"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:focusable="true"
                 android:padding="10dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/cnbc_default_image"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/supportImageView"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:src="@drawable/video_play_icon"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/title"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@id/title"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/description"
                    style="@style/large_news_title_text_style"/>

            <TextView android:id="@id/description"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:maxLines="2"
                      android:ellipsize="end"
                      android:textSize="13sp"
                      style="@style/large_news_title_text_style"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then finally add the inflated view to the linearlayout instance using

row.addView(inflatedView);

However, the end result is first box stretching across X axis.  If i inspect my layout using HierachyViewer, i do see 3 RelativeLayouts inside a LinearLayout, but the first one is occupying all the space.

The thumbnail image android:id="@+id/thumbnail", seems to be taking up match_parent attribute of the LinearLayout and not its immediate container RelativeLayout.

**Clarification**

The list view is from ListFragment.
When adding the box layout to the list view row container i use this method call

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row_land, parent, false);

View rowItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row_item,null);

container.addView(rowItem);
```

Solved:
The problem is solved if i modify the layout of the box to

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="500dp"
                 android:layout_height="300dp"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:focusable="true"
                 android:padding="10dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/cnbc_default_image"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/supportImageView"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:src="@drawable/video_play_icon"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/title"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@id/title"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/description"
                    style="@style/large_news_title_text_style"/>

            <TextView android:id="@id/description"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:maxLines="2"
                      android:ellipsize="end"
                      android:textSize="13sp"
                      style="@style/large_news_title_text_style"
                      android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I still don't understand why. So any explanation of why putting a LinearLayout around solves the issue will be helpful.

Comment: What `LayoutParams` have you set to the `ListView`? You can add that code as well.

Comment: Added some clarification.Is that what you asked for @JoelFernandes

Comment: Well, I just noticed this. Try changing the `width` and `height` of `@+id/thumbnail` to `wrap_content`

Comment: If i do that , the image becomes small but the,  TextView android:id="@id/description" spans across the width of the list view, which is understandable since it has match_parent. My question is why match_parent on thumbnail is not matching with the RelativeLayout container?

Comment: @JoelFernandes: The problem is solved, please see my answer. However, i'm still unclear about the why it was not working before.